# Symfony 4: services are shown in the console but not autoinject

Tags: symfony, symfony4

```
hett@hett-pc:/data/projects/graylist$ ./bin/console  debug:container | grep client_manager
  fos_oauth_server.client_manager                alias for "fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default"                                     
  fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default        FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\ClientManager
```

I can use the service in my command:

```
class TestCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'test';
    private $clientManager;

    public function __construct(?string $name = null, \FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\ClientManager $clientManager)
    {
        $this->clientManager = $clientManager;
        parent::__construct($name);
    }
}
```

But get error

> Cannot autowire service "App\Command\TestCommand": argument
>   "$clientManager" of method "__construct()" references class
>   "FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\ClientManager" but no such service
>   exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a di
>   fferent root namespace.

Why?

And how I can associate default service with `ClientManagerInterface` ?

PS: I tried to inject `ClientManagerInterface` too, but got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps, I found answers faster than writing the question:

This service does not support autowiring, need to add line below to `services.yaml`:

```
services:
    FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\ClientManagerInterface: '@fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default'
```